# How to extract defines from a header?

Tags: preprocessor, meson-build

I would like to extract some defines from header files, and put the result into a meson variables. I can of course do that with `run_command`, forming a shell command of cpp, sed and so on. But I wonder if meson gives some automation to that task. Having `run_preprocessor` would already be a win, but there seem to be no such
thing. Also `get_compiler` method does exist, but `get_preprocessor` - seemingly not. At least I could refer to a currently selected preprocessor
and use the current include paths, rather than just using `cpp` in `run_command` with a hard-coded path to headers.

Does meson provide at least some help for extracting things from headers, or should it be coded by hands, with a pure `run_command`?

Answer (score 2):

This is normally done via [compiler.get_define](https://mesonbuild.com/Reference-manual_returned_compiler.html#compilerget_define), which would look something like:

```
cpp = meson.get_compiler('cpp')
cpp_ver = cpp.get_define('__cplusplus')
```

There are additional arguments for handling dependencies, header search paths, and generating a preamble for the test, which I think the linked documentation describes well enough

Comment: Even looking into the doc you pointed, I still don't understand how to pass the exact header which I want to extract from?

Comment: OK, got it, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Based on @dcbaker reply, I've come up with this:

```
incdir = include_directories('some_inc_dir')
cpp = meson.get_compiler('c')
VAR = cpp.get_define('MY_DEFINE',
  include_directories: incdir,
  prefix: '#include "my_hdr.h"')
```

Comment: That works, I would use the `prefix` keyword argument like so: `cpp.get_define('MY_DEFINE', include_directories : incdir, prefix : '#include "my_hdr.h"')` Prefix is not a super descriptive name.

Comment: I edited the reply to use prefix.